# Deploying MVC 3 App to multiple sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 app that I need to deploy.  The app was developed as one application but due to requirements changes it needs to be split into 2 pieces on the staging, test and live servers.  However, each piece share models and contollers.

My project structure looks like this:
•   *Views*
o   **FolderOne**
   Page1
   Page2
o   **Account**
   Logon
   Register
o   **Home**
   Index
o   **FolderTwo**
   Page1
   Page2
o   **Phone**
   Page1
   Page2

The folder structure in IIS looks like this:

c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\FolderOne  contains Views(FolderOne,Account,Home,FolderTwo)

c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Phone contains Phone

My question is, how is the best way to deploy this?  Should I just copy the bin folder and supporting files and folders to each place in IIS?

Rhonda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should to copy all required files to test web app, and edit web.config (or custom config file) to work with test database.
If your models and controllers is stored in separate assembly, you can deploy these assembly to GAC and use share assembly without require to copy to test web app.